# How to create and load a 3 dim numpy.ndarray reading from npy files?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, reshape

I have different .npy files, in which there are saved numpy arrays (or images represented as matrices, with a dimension = 64, the other one I don't know).

I want to read them, store them in a numpy.ndarray of 3 dimensions.

What I have done till now is something very different, and I'm having problems dealing with the structures I created.

```
database_list = list()
labels_list = list()

for filename in glob.glob('*.npy'):
  database_list.append(np.load(filename))
  label_temp = extract_label(filename)
  labels_list.append(label_temp)

database = np.array(database_list)
labels = np.array(labels_list)
```

In that way, I have a numpy.ndarray `database` of shape `(n_elements,)`.

Let's assume that I reshape each image as (n, 64), I want `database` to be of the shape `(n_elements, n, 64)`.

How can I do it?

What I want to achieve is an array of the same shape of MNIST database, for working on neural network.

EDIT:

`database` type is `numpy.ndarray`. It can't be reshaped, `database` is of size n, say 10 (because it is composed of n elements, for example 10 if 10 files are loaded. The files are matrices of two dimensions, but I want them to be "part of" database).

Comment: What is `database.dtype`?  Probably object.  That means that `database_list` contains arrays with varying shapes.   Load a small set of the files, and print `[x.shape for x in database_list]` to check the shapes.

Comment: What is your question? Are you just asking how to reshape NumPy arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj ok I tried reshaping the images before loading them in the numpy array, and automatically the array became of shape (n_elements, dim1, dim2). Thx. If you write it as answer I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `database = np.array(database_list)` to make a 3d array with shape `(n_elements, dim1, dim2)`, the `database_list` has to contain arrays all with the shape (dim1, dim2).  If they differ in shape the result will be a (n_elements,) shaped array with object dtype (or in some cases it will throw an error).